# Turning nested curly braces into a dict python

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have a file that looks like this:

```
{val1 {val2 {d1 d2 d3}}}
```

I would like to make a dict or another suitable data structure so that accessing the structure like so:

```
data[val1][val2]
```

will output the data values `d1, d2, d3` in another suitable data structure such as a list, tuple, or set.

Is there a built-in library function that can do this or can anyone suggest an easy way to do this?

Note: the number of data points `d1 d2 d3` may not be constant, so for a different set of values I could have `d1 d2 d3 d4 d5` etc.

Edit: I should add that I wrote the output, so I can change the braces to something completely different if needs be.

Comment: This isn't really a common format, so no, there is no built-in function to handle this. Write code to tokenise, parse, and spit out a dictionary.

Comment: Here is a quickie to help with dictionary-izing it `replace('{', ':{')[1:]`

Comment: It's not gonna be easy. Your values are enclosed in `{ }` but you want them as `[ ]`

Comment: Depending on how many of these you have, it might be easier to convert the file to, say, YAML (or JSON) first and then use the libraries.

Comment: If you can change the output format, then switch to JSON.

Comment: @TimCastelijns: unless they want the value to be a set..

Comment: @user1654183: What do you mean by "I wrote the output". Did you choose the format? It would be better to use a standard format such as json.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all your data is as simple as the example, you can do some string manipulation to turn it into json.

```
import re, json
data = '{val1 {val2 {d1 d2 d3}}}'
data = re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'"\1"', data)      # {"val1" {"val2" {"d1" "d2" "d3"}}}
data = re.sub(r'"\s*{', r'": {', data)      # {"val1": {"val2": {"d1" "d2" "d3"}}}
data = re.sub(r'" "', r'", "', data)        # {"val1": {"val2": {"d1", "d2", "d3"}}}
data = re.sub(r'{([^{}]*)}', r'[\1]', data) # {"val1": {"val2": ["d1", "d2", "d3"]}}
json.loads(data)
```

If you also have data with more complex nesting, you will probably have to add a step or two more to add or remove commas before it is valid json.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what will you do exactly with this data but according to information you give, this seem useful. At least it may give you an idea and you can manipulate the converter as you wish.

______exampledata.txt

```
{a{a{hello world}}}
{a{b{stack over flow}}}
{b{a{example data 1}}}
{b{b{data example 2}}}
```

______converter.py

```
import os

fo = open("exampledata.txt", "r")
data = fo.read()
fo.close()

data = data.split("\n")

fo = open("converteddata.txt", "w")
for line in data:
    line = line.split("{")
    if len(line) < 2:
        break
    fo.write("data['")
    fo.write(line[1]+"-"+line[2]+"'] = [")
    splitData = line[3].split("}}}")[0]
    splitData = splitData.split(" ")
    for d in splitData:
        fo.write("'"+d+"', ")
    fo.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
    fo.truncate()
    fo.write("]\n")
```

______converteddata.txt (converter will produce this)

```
data['a-a'] = ['hello', 'world']
data['a-b'] = ['stack', 'over', 'flow']
data['b-a'] = ['example', 'data', '1']
data['b-b'] = ['data', 'example', '2']
```

______usage of converted data

```
data = dict()

data["a-a"] = ["hello", "world"]
data["a-b"] = ["stack", "over", "flow"]
data["b-a"] = ["example", "data", "1"]
data["b-b"] = ["data", "example", "2"]

val1 = raw_input("Please enter first parameter : ")
val2 = raw_input("Please enter second parameter : ")
index = raw_input("Please enter index : ")

print data[val1+"-"+val2][int(index)]
```

EDIT : You will not copy/paste converted data to your main project. If you have big data, your main project file seem really bad. So you can create a converteddata.py which is

```
data = dict()

data['a-a'] = ['hello', 'world']
data['a-b'] = ['stack', 'over', 'flow']
data['b-a'] = ['example', 'data', '1']
data['b-b'] = ['data', 'example', '2']
```

then you can import it to your main project like

```
from converteddata import data

print data["a-a"][0]
```